# How to store null elements in some object array and to know they are stored intentionally(not generated by java)

Tags: java, arrays, null

I am creating ExpandableArray class what contains Product classes inside.
I have method add(Product p) that adds Product in first null position in my ExpandableArray.
And method replace(index int, Product p) - replaces product with this index by with p.

i have confronted following situation:

```
ExpandableArray expArr = new ExpandableArray(3); // let initial size be 3 products.
expArr.add(p1);
expArr.add(p2);
expArr.replace(0,null) // [null,p2,null].
```

notice that i replaced first element by null intentionally! method add shouldn't touch it, it should work with the second null.

But how do i do that?

My solution is to make `integer[]intentionedNullIndexes` array inside `ExpandableArray`, and it will contain all indexes will intentioned nulls. so method add firstly will check if this null index is in intentionedNullIndexes and if it is he won't touch it.

i don't like this solution because it's hard to implement and wastes MANY RAM. Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you want to achieve with the null values? Probably I am missing something - why and how should JAVA generate null values in your array?

Comment: @the-incredible-jan i mean whenever my array is full i create another with bigger size and copy the last array elements into new one. but new elements are filled with nulls automatically(java works so)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your requirement is an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

It's an antipattern when `null` has some kind of special meaning in your business logic. The only valid meaning of `null` -  is no data (*otherwise the code becomes muddy*).

> i don't like this solution because it's hard to implement and wastes MANY RAM

There's no need to waste lots of memory. You need only **one reference** to a placeholder object, which you can use as many times as you need.

Comment: That's what i meant! First null in my example means no data there. 

Like if i have expArray with my birthday gifts from 3 family members first null is there intentionally and it means first kin told me: "I will give you nothing, no present from me." (what product could i use? surely null only, i can't create any product with meaning "nothing".). second null is not intentioned, it means i don't know will third kin give me something or no. Is this logic still antipattern?

Comment: @NathanIkazuyir I'm quite sure from your response if you understand me. An *Array* is a data structure which occupies a contiguous block of memory, i.e. regardless of whether you're storing anything in it **or not**, even if all values are `null` this memory is already taken, you can't gain extra space by changing values `null` (hope that's clear?). If you need to mark certain indices in the array - place the **same object** here (`java.lang.Object`, `String`, whatever), the key point the extra memory you need to allocate a **single object** is neglectable in comparison with a massive array.